# is there any way to make css pseudo-class input:focus not to effect when filed is readonly,GWT/MGWT

Tags: css, gwt, textfield, readonly, mgwt

I'm developing a mobile app using GWT,MGWT and HTML,CSS, My view having some text fields some of the fields among them are readonly. I used css pseudo-class in my css file as follows:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #FFFACD;
}
```

it is working fine when field is editable meaning text filed background is changing with #FFFACD when cursor pointed there, if we click/tap non-editable field the above is also effecting which I dont want to see. I even tried like below::

```
input[type=text]:disabled{
    background-color:  transparent;
}
```

But I'm getting nothing from above. 
How can I prevent css effect on readOnly filed. I'm making filed as readonly by doing like this. `tf.setReadOnly(true);`. Waiting for your valuable suggestion.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your selector to this:

```
input:not([readonly])[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: #FFFACD;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha3rg70f/)

---

`:not` is [well supported](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) (except for IE < 9).